# How to kill bullet after a certain of distance?

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

How to kill bullet after a certain amount of time, or certain amount of distance ? I'm using JavaScript and [Phaser 3](https://phaser.io/phaser3).

```js
if (keyA.isDown && time > lastFired || isDown && time > lastFired) {
          
            var bullet = bullets.create(player.x , player.y, 'bullet');
            
            bullet.setVelocity( -800, 0);
            lastFired = time + 90;

        }
```

Comment: Are you using a game framework? What language are you using?

Comment: Hi I am using Javascript , phaser3

Answer (score 0):

If it should be after some time, you could do something like this.
*(here some more details from the Docs: [from the Docs](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/timer/) )*

But to be honest I don't know, if this would impact the performance, or not.

```js
 ...  
// the 500 ist the timeout in ms
this.time.delayedCall(500, () => bullet.destroy();  
....
```

*(add this line after creating the bullet)*

Or you cout use a time event

```js
this.time.addEvent({
    delay: 500,
    callback: ()=>{
        bullet.destroy()
    },
    loop: false
});
```

**for destroying by distance:** depending if it is one bullet or many. you could add the bullet to a `group` and check the distance in the `update` function, and it its too far you detroy it/them.